# How can we define the supremum norm on the space of continuous functions if they're not necessarily bounded?

Tags: continuity, uniform-convergence, supremum-and-infimum, uniform-spaces

I frequently see the uniform norm described as a norm on the space of continuous functions $C(Y, X)$ where $Y$ is a topological space and $X$ is a metric space, especially in the context of the uniform limit theorem. How is it possible to define such a norm when functions which are continuous need not be bounded?

Specifically, in $C(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ the function $f(x) = x$ is continuous and yet
$$
    \|f\|_{\infty} = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f(x)|
$$
is not well defined (by the definition of a norm which requires it to be a real valued function on the space).

Comment: As you defined it, that's indeed not a norm. You need some more restrictions - for example, to assume that $Y$ is a compact space, or to define this only on compactly supported continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You can take a family of seminorms and define a topological vector space structure on it.

Comment: It's common to first define an "extended norm" (don't know if there is another name for it) with values in $[0,\infty) \cup \{\infty\}$ on a linear space, and then take the subset where the norm in finite. This is for example done when defining $L^p$ spaces.

Comment: First select the functions for which $\sup |f|$ is finite and then define the norm.

Answer (score 1):

1. The uniform norm is typically defined on a space of bounded functions.
2. The norm is a function that takes an argument from it's domain and produces a real number out of it. If $f$ is not bounded, there is no way it is a part of a domain of the sup norm.